# Get realtime information from Google Analytics Data API (GA4) like UsersBysource, EventCountByEventName and eventParamerts

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters, google-analytics-4

I want get the events by names a filter the information like screen_view->firebase_screen_class and get Users by source, medium and camping

[image: Event count by event names and event pUsers by source, medium and campaignarameters]

Answer (score 0):

James,

The Data API realtime reporting functionality supports [eventName dimension, as well as User scoped custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-api-schema).

Reporting by source, medium and campaign is only supported by [regular (non-realtime) query method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics).

Comment: Do you have an example how to code that? The documentation from the Google Data API Report does not have nothing about get that.